# How to add a button in the tab bar of JTabbedPane, that is not a tab?

Tags: java, button, tabs, jtabbedpane

I want to add a JButton to the tab bar of my JTabbedPane and this button shouldn't be a tab! Or to maybe say it more clearly, i want to add another component to the area where tabs reside.

How can i achieve this? Which part of the JTabbedPane do i have to rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quess i found the answer to my question by myself: JIDE has (in there open source lib) a JideTabbedPane that can show a component before or after the tab bar. That's what i wanted.
I would love to write this thing for myself but it looks like that isn't that easy, so i will end up adding this lib...

[JIDE OSS](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm)